# Optimization of inlined values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, gcc, inline

I have the following inline method and call it several times in other methods. Will the vc and gcc compilers with O2 optimization be able to notice the value is fixed in the calling methods and evaluated it only once? -- Indeed `indexAndFlag` is not changed inside those methods. -- Or, maybe for thread-safety, it will be evaluated per each call?

```c
unsigned int indexAndFlag;
...

inline Index* index() const
{
    return (Index*)(indexAndFlag & ~1);
}
```

The code is only for protected mode  x86 32/64bit architecture, so I hope, I can assume `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(Index*)`. If not, please correct me.

Comment: It's probably best to check. objdump -d ...

Comment: I don't know what protected mode for x86/64 will be, but you can assert whether the sizes are the same or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as it seems to be, `indexAndFlag` is a non-const non-static global, then no. The compiler has no way to determine whether or not another translation unit might modify it, and so the program must access its value wherever it's used.

If it were `const`, and initialised with a constant expression, then the compiler must treat it as a constant value, and your expression *should* also be treated as a constant value.

> I hope, I can assume `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(Index*)`

I wouldn't: many popular 64-bit architectures have a 32-bit `int`. Use `uintptr_t` to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. But will `indexAndFlag & ~1` be correctly for `uintptr_t indexAndFlag`? Wouldn't it have 32 0s in the case of 32bit int and 64 pointer?

Comment: @Number47: Yes, you should also use `~uintptr_t(1)`. Or `~mask`, having declared `const uintptr_t mask = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

To start from the bottom: `sizeof(unsigned int) != sizeof(Index *)` in 64-bit, that's for sure. And if you are making that assumption, I would definitely suggest that you use a `static_assert(sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(Index *))` somewhere in the code.

Next, what the compiler does or doesn't do with regards to global variables and optimization is definitely a case of "up to the compiler". The compiler may well decide to re-load the value each time, or it may decide that "Ah, I know this doesn't change". It really depends on how well it "understands" that `indexAndFlag` is not changing.

I personally would use something like:

```
 Index* temp = index();

  ... 
   use temp
  ...
```

Then it's guaranteed that no extra operations are made to "calculate" the index.